# python mapping with strings

Tags: python, string, dictionary, lambda

I implemented a version of the str_replace function available in php using python. Here is my original code that didn't work

```
def replacer(items,str,repl):
    return "".join(map(lambda x:repl if x in items else x,str))

test = "hello world"
print test
test = replacer(test,['e','l','o'],'?')
print test
```

but this prints out

```
hello world
???
```

the code i got to do as expected is

```
def replacer(str,items,repl):
    x = "".join(map(lambda x:repl if x in items else x,str))
    return x

test = "hello world"
print test
test = replacer(test,['e','l','o'],'?')
print test
```

which prints out

```
 hello world
 h???? w?r?d
```

just like I wanted it to.

Aside from the fact that there is probably a way using builtins that i haven't seen yet, why does the first way fail and the second way do what I need it to?

Comment: I hate it when a simple cosmetic change is invisible to me and causes my things to not work right but I forget about the change i made!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordering of the arguments to `replacer` is what makes the difference between the two.  If you changed the argument ordering in the first version it'd behave like the second version.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use built-in names such as `str` for your own identifiers, that's just asking for trouble and has **no** benefit whatsoever.

Apart from that, your first version is looping on `str`, the **second** argument -- the list `['e', 'l', 'o']` -- so **of course** it will return a string of exactly three items -- how could you expect it to return a string of any other length?!  Using `str` to name a *list* argument is *particularly* perverse and bug-prone.

The second version loops on `str`, the **first** argument -- the string `'hello world'` so of course it's returning a string of *that* length.

Comment: i know it was just a quick example i was trying to show one of my friends who does a lot of php

Comment: is there a way to do multiple replacement like this with the builtin string methods or is a small piece of code like this what I need each time?

Comment: @controlfreak, the `.translate` method of strings is much better (but for bytestrings in Python `2.*` you have to prep a translate table with `string.maketrans` first -- Unicode objects, and Python 3 strings which are also unicode, are neater as they take a `dict`).

Answer (score 1):

You're passing it in backwards in the first one.  It should be should be

```
test = replacer(['e','l','o'], test, '?')
```